# Extract values from pop-ups in Esri MapServer

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I have access to an ESRI MapServer that contains several layers; how can I get the values out of those layers and export it?

Example:

MapServer (https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA/MapServer/2) has a layer "States". The Rest point shows me this layer and what each field within that layer is, but that's it. I want to get a list of areas, which is one of the fields of the "States" layer. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Too long for comments...

to list the field names:

```
https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA/MapServer/2/query?where=1%3D1&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=state_name&returnGeometry=false&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&having=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=state_name&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&historicMoment=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&queryByDistance=&returnExtentOnly=false&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&quantizationParameters=&featureEncoding=esriDefault&f=pjson
```

returns

```
 "displayFieldName": "state_name",
 "fieldAliases": {
  "state_name": "STATE_NAME"
 },
 "fields": [
  {
   "name": "state_name",
   "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
   "alias": "STATE_NAME",
   "length": 25
  }
 ],
 "features": [
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Alabama"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Alaska"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Arizona"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Arkansas"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "California"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Colorado"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Connecticut"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Delaware"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "District of Columbia"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Florida"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Georgia"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Hawaii"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Idaho"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Illinois"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Indiana"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Iowa"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Kansas"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Kentucky"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Louisiana"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Maine"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Maryland"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Massachusetts"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Michigan"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Minnesota"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Mississippi"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Missouri"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Montana"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Nebraska"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Nevada"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "New Hampshire"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "New Jersey"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "New Mexico"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "New York"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "North Carolina"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "North Dakota"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Ohio"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Oklahoma"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Oregon"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Pennsylvania"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Rhode Island"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "South Carolina"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "South Dakota"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Tennessee"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Texas"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Utah"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Vermont"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Virginia"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Washington"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "West Virginia"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Wisconsin"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "state_name": "Wyoming"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get that data through arcpy (or python in general)? For this example, the end result that I need is a python list of the states.

Comment: yes there is lots of examples online. https://developers.arcgis.com/python/